# Dim Display in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, screen, brightness, 20.04

i recently upgraded my HP laptop from 19.10 to 20.04 , after the upgrade my screen is always in dim display , if i watch videos in full screen , display getting correctly else dim display only. Screen brightness , turnoff dim display an laptop charging mode nothing getting helps. t.t

not able attache the screenshot as image is dull and giving the error.

like to revert back to 19.10 ..

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could write directly to the file that manages screen brightness. 
On my laptop, this is:

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

and it accepts values up to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

To know the latter, you can: `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`.

To change screen brightness:

`sudo echo 4000 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Hope that helps.

Comment: It seems my profile was corrupted causing the issue . Deleted my profile and with new profile login it was fixed.